# pandas drop rows based on column value drops wrong row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, drop

I am trying to drop rows based on a column value.  I have tried ideas from other answers but it seems to drop a row that it shouldn't.
This is part of the dataframe as a csv:

```
YEAR,MO,GP,HR,qty,SKYMEAN,SKY100MEAN,SKY100STD,SKY100MEDIAN
1973,1,1,0,1,7,87.5,,87.5
1973,1,1,14,1,8,100,,100
1973,1,1,15,4,5.25,65.625,43.75,87.5
1973,1,1,16,12,4.416666667,55.20833333,48.98351222,87.5
1973,1,1,17,22,5.227272727,65.34090909,43.80214888,87.5
1973,1,1,18,21,5.095238095,63.69047619,39.70688737,87.5
1973,1,1,19,20,5.2,65,39.23612728,87.5
1973,1,1,20,32,5.15625,64.453125,36.63097565,87.5
1973,1,1,21,19,5.526315789,69.07894737,37.5851859,87.5
1973,1,1,22,12,6.083333333,76.04166667,35.93647067,87.5
1973,1,1,24,144,5.263888889,65.79861111,39.13917785,87.5
1973,2,1,0,1,8,100,,100
1973,2,1,15,1,7,87.5,,87.5
1973,2,1,16,10,5.4,67.5,35.93976442,87.5
1973,2,1,17,24,4.458333333,55.72916667,44.83956404,87.5
1973,2,1,18,20,4.4,55,42.2243382,56.25
1973,2,1,19,21,4.714285714,58.92857143,43.50697809,87.5
1973,2,1,20,26,5,62.5,43.30127019,87.5
1973,2,1,21,22,5.636363636,70.45454545,39.8183103,87.5
1973,2,1,22,4,6,75,33.85016002,87.5
1973,2,1,23,2,7.5,93.75,8.838834765,93.75
1973,2,1,24,131,5.007633588,62.59541985,41.32703132,87.5
```

I have tried the following:

```
sample_data.drop(sample_data[sample_data['qty'] < 5].index, inplace = True)
sample_data.reset_index(drop=True)
```

The results are that the Hour 24 is dropped when it should not be:

```
YEAR,MO,GP,HR,qty,SKYMEAN,SKY100MEAN,SKY100STD,SKY100MEDIAN
1973,1,1,16,12,4.416666667,55.20833333,48.98351222,87.5
1973,1,1,17,22,5.227272727,65.34090909,43.80214888,87.5
1973,1,1,18,21,5.095238095,63.69047619,39.70688737,87.5
1973,1,1,19,20,5.2,65,39.23612728,87.5
1973,1,1,20,32,5.15625,64.453125,36.63097565,87.5
1973,1,1,21,19,5.526315789,69.07894737,37.5851859,87.5
1973,1,1,22,12,6.083333333,76.04166667,35.93647067,87.5
1973,2,1,16,10,5.4,67.5,35.93976442,87.5
1973,2,1,17,24,4.458333333,55.72916667,44.83956404,87.5
1973,2,1,18,20,4.4,55,42.2243382,56.25
1973,2,1,19,21,4.714285714,58.92857143,43.50697809,87.5
1973,2,1,20,26,5,62.5,43.30127019,87.5
1973,2,1,21,22,5.636363636,70.45454545,39.8183103,87.5
```

I also tried:

```
filter2 = sample_data['qty'] >= 5
sample_data[filter2]
sample_data.reset_index(drop=True)
```

But it does absolutely nothing to the data. The results are the same as the original data.
I have used the df.drop() function in other modules and they work just fine.
I don't know why the HR (Hour) column of value 24 is getting dropped because it is certainly greater than 5.
Any ideas?  Am I missing something in the drop function?

Comment: make sure to assign the output in the second code: `out = sample_data[filter2].reset_index(drop=True)` then `print(out)`

Comment: Regarding the first code, you probably have duplicated indices. Relying on the index to drop is not a fail-proof method.

Comment: Thank you mozway.  Both of your suggestions worked.